# Attaching overrides to a C# class

Tags: c#, overriding, aop

I have a class with functions:

```
class MyClass
{
    public List<Attachment> Attachments;

    public void A()
    {
        // Do something
    }
    public void B()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

class AttachmentA : Attachment
{
    public void A()
    {
        // Do something else
        RealA();
    }
}

class AttachmentB : Attachment
{
    public void B()
    {
        // Do something else
        // RealB();
        // No need to call base function here
    }
}
```

I need in my code when I attach `AttachmentA` to `MyClass` that all the functions in `MyClass` that are also present in `AttachmentA` to be overridden by the functions in `AttachmentA` and also give access to the original functions in `MyClass`.
For example, I create `MyClass` and then attach `AttachmentA` instance to it. calling `MyClass.A()` will actually call `AttachmentA.A()` and the `AttachmentA.RealA()` will call the base function that was overridden.
I know this can be somehow done with something like using event handlers lists to handle overrides but is there an easy way to implement this?
Edit: I have no problem with long code that uses reflection as long as its present once and doesn't have to be even mentioned in any of the functions - maybe only when attaching attachement.

Edit: you wanted an example:

```
class MyClass
{
    public List<Attachment> Attachments;

    public MyClass()
    {
        Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
    }
    public void Attach(Attachment attachment)
    {
        Attachments.Add(attachment);
        // Do some magic here
    }
    public void A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyClass.A");
    }
    public void B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyClass.B");
    }
}

class AttachmentA : Attachment
{
    public void A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AttachmentA.A");
        RealA();
    }
}

class AttachmentB : Attachment
{
    public void B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AttachmentB.B");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] Args)
    {
        MyClass aaa = new MyClass();
        aaa.A(); // should print MyClass.A
        aaa.B(); // should print MyClass.B
        aaa.Attach(new AttachmentA());
        aaa.Attach(new AttachmentB());
        aaa.A(); // should print AttachmentA.A <newline> MyClass.A
        aaa.B(); // should print AttachmentB.B
    }
}
```

Edit: What I want to achieve here is like unit with attributes( = attachments). When the unit get an attachment of `RandomSpeed`, `RandomSpeed` will override the unit's `GetSpeed` and return random value. when it will get an attachment of evasion, it will override that units `ReduceHP` function and sometimes based on random value will not call the base function.

Edit: What will really solve this mess is to somehow use reflection to change virtual method tables, I'm gonna make a followup on a separate question. I keep this question here incase someone find a better way to do this.

Comment: Short answer: No! But if you give more details about what you really want to do, you have better chances to get a helpful answer.

Comment: Huh? Your question is very unclear.  Please add an example.

Comment: Search for aspect oriented programming.

Comment: Why do you want to use this? Can you please exlain what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Wessel Kranenborg, @SLaks added the answers

Comment: What if two attachments call `RealA()`? What if one does and the other doesn't?

Comment: So one will and other wont? like you can choose to call base class

Comment: Decorator Pattern? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: The decorator pattern is what I'm looking for, thanks. (put it in an answer so I can accept it).

Comment: you dont need to change virtual methdo tables, or use reflection. You have both feet on the wrong path. It will seriously hurt performance if you continue onto it. Delegates is the solution to such a need (ie selectively changing methods that execute).

Comment: decorator pattern is fit yes, use that, but seriously dont' go into reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, Decorator Pattern is what you are looking for.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

> The decorator pattern can be used to
>   make it possible to extend (decorate)
>   the functionality of a certain object
>   at runtime, independently of other
>   instances of the same class, provided
>   some groundwork is done at design
>   time. This is achieved by designing a
>   new decorator class that wraps the
>   original class.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to introduce dependencies, like inheritance or interfaces to implement on MyClass then:

You can achieve this through delegates.

Long story short, you cannot override function in runtime without resorting to some obscure reflection magic, but you can declare delegates instead of functions. When you construct your class in the constructor fill the delegates with private methods which will be used for as long as no AttachmentA class comes in. And use those delegates instead of the methods.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass aaa = new MyClass();
            aaa.A(); // should print MyClass.A
            aaa.B(); // should print MyClass.B
            aaa.Attach(new AttachmentA());
            aaa.Attach(new AttachmentB());
            aaa.A(); // should print AttachmentA.A <newline> MyClass.A
            aaa.B(); // should print AttachmentB.B
        }

    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public List<Attachment> Attachments;

        public MyClass()
        {
            A = _A;
            B = _B;
            Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        }
        public void Attach(Attachment attachment)
        {
            Attachments.Add(attachment);

            // this is your magic
            if (attachment.GetType() == typeof(AttachmentA)) {
                A = ((AttachmentA)attachment).A;
            }
            else if (attachment.GetType() == typeof(AttachmentB))
            {
                B = ((AttachmentB)attachment).B;
            }
        }

        public delegate void delegateA();
        public delegate void delegateB();

        public delegateA A;
        public delegateB B;

        public void _A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyClass.A");
        }
        public void _B()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyClass.B");
        }
    }

    class Attachment { 
    }

    class AttachmentA : Attachment
    {
        public void A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AttachmentA.A");
        }
    }

    class AttachmentB : Attachment
    {
        public void B()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AttachmentB.B");
        }
    }
}
```

If you need the execution to start always in MyClass instead of the Attachment class you can wrap the delegates like here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass aaa = new MyClass();
            aaa.A(); // should print MyClass.A
            aaa.B(); // should print MyClass.B
            aaa.Attach(new AttachmentA());
            aaa.Attach(new AttachmentB());
            aaa.A(); // should print AttachmentA.A <newline> MyClass.A
            aaa.B(); // should print AttachmentB.B
        }

    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public List<Attachment> Attachments;

        public MyClass()
        {
            Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        }

        public void Attach(Attachment attachment)
        {
            Attachments.Add(attachment);

            if (attachment.GetType() == typeof(AttachmentA)) {
                _A = ((AttachmentA)attachment).A;
            }
            else if (attachment.GetType() == typeof(AttachmentB))
            {
                _B = ((AttachmentB)attachment).B;
            }
        }

        public delegate void delegateA();
        public delegate void delegateB();

        public delegateA _A;
        public delegateB _B;

        public void A()
        {
            if (_A != null)
            {
                _A();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("MyClass.A");
            }
        }
        public void B()
        {
            if (_B != null)
            {
                _B();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("MyClass.B");
            }
        }
    }

    class Attachment { 
    }

    class AttachmentA : Attachment
    {
        public void A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AttachmentA.A");
        }
    }

    class AttachmentB : Attachment
    {
        public void B()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AttachmentB.B");
        }
    }
}
```

You can shorten this to one delegate type if A and B have the same parameters and return type in your real scenario.

Comment: But that will make code for each function be more complex and not behind the scenes.

Comment: yes but it can selectively override at runtime, inheritance cannot, it all depends on the base type and the derived type... and what the you need. If you dont need this then use inheritance if it fits, however you should have considered that already, that is why i'm talking about delegates.

Answer (score 2):

Why not take another approach? Have attachments implement interfaces based on what they want to override, for example ISpeedAttachment. Then you could, in the base speed function loop through attachments which implement ISpeedAttachment, calling them.

Have the interfaces return null if they haven't taken effect and you could then check they've all returned null and call the base class as appropriate, or pass in a ref parameter which you could adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the [behavioral patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_pattern). For your particular problem I would recommend either the [chain of responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) or the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if dynamically overriding a class's functionality is possible, but you can achieve something similar by using different interfaces. Depending on the context you want to use this in, it may require only small redesign.

The standard way of doing it would be this:

```
using System;

class MyClass
{
    public virtual void A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyClass.A");
    }
    public virtual void B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyClass.B");
    }
}

class ClassA : MyClass
{
    public override void A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AttachmentA.A");

        base.A();
    }
}

class ClassB : MyClass
{
    public override void B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AttachmentB.B");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] Args)
    {
        MyClass aaa = new ClassA();
        MyClass bbb = new ClassB();

        aaa.A(); // prints MyClass.A
        aaa.B(); // prints MyClass.B
        (aaa as ClassA).A(); // prints AttachmentA.A
        (aaa as ClassA).B(); // prints MyClass.B
        bbb.A(); // prints MyClass.A
        bbb.B(); // prints MyClass.B
        (bbb as ClassB).A(); // prints AttachmentB.A + MyClass.A
        (bbb as ClassB).B(); // prints AttachmentB.B
    }
}
```

Here's another example, similar to what blowdart suggested:

```
interface ICallMe
{
    bool A();
    bool B();
}

class MyClass
{
    public ICallMe Attachment { get; set; }

    public void A()
    {
        bool BaseFunction = true;
        if (Attachment != null)
            BaseFunction = Attachment.A();

        if (BaseFunction)
            Console.WriteLine("MyClass.A");
    }

    public void B()
    {
        bool BaseFunction = true;
        if (Attachment != null)
            BaseFunction = Attachment.B();

        if (BaseFunction)
            Console.WriteLine("MyClass.B");
    }
}

class ClassA : ICallMe
{
    public bool A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AttachmentA.A");

        return true;
    }

    public bool B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AttachmentA.B");

        return false;
    }
}

static class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass aaa = new MyClass();
        aaa.A(); // prints MyClass.A
        aaa.B(); // prints MyClass.B
        aaa.Attachment = new ClassA();
        aaa.A(); // should print AttachmentA.A <newline> MyClass.A
        aaa.B(); // should print AttachmentB.B
    }
}
```

This only allows for a single attachment to be added. If you wanted to override the behavior of several functions separately, you could use a Collection of some sort to hold the attachments. Within the base class you'd need to loop through them and find the one you want to execute.

Comment: I dont see what can print AttachmentB.A (one before last line) here

Comment: Since A() isn't overridden in ClassB, it'll print whatever is defined in the base class MyClass, which is "MyClass.B".